# How to know whether iPhone's clock changed while app is running?

Tags: ios, iphone, clock

will UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification work if user set automatically setting clock in iOS's General setting, and the clock of the device changes because of the carrier time change?
Is there any other way to get notified when system clock changes while app is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation says yes, it is called due to carrier time changes.

"Posted when there is a significant change in time, for example, change to a new day (midnight), carrier time update, and change to or from daylight savings time.
This notification does not contain a userInfo dictionary"

Answer (score 1):

The `UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification` notification is sent at midnight or anytime the device's time changes (such as daylight savings, the user changing the time, timezone changes, etc.). I don't have direct knowledge of whether changes in time from the carrier will trigger this notification but given the other events, I'd be surprised if such a change didn't trigger the notification.